# Why do we lose signal in elevators?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields

Whenever I am talking on my phone and walk into the elevator the call drops as soon as the doors close, and also the WiFi signal completely stops.

Why does this happen?

Note: I am asking this question because me and my friends are brainstorming for a project proposal to work on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The limit of radio wave penetration](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30504/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I am looking for more details which would lead me into studying topics to be the basis of a research.

Comment: As that article points out, a Faraday cage pretty much explains it.

Answer (score 2):

To a very good approximation, the electric field inside a conductor is zero when there is no net transport of charge across the conductor.  Since an electromagnetic field is dependent on varying electric fields, there is an inherent block against electromagnetic waves penetrating very far into closed metal surfaces under most circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

The metal box of the elevator will reflect most microwaves that are incident upon it (that works for waves coming inwards from outside, or vice versa).

Then, even if some microwaves do penetrate into the metal, they are rapidly attenuated by resistive losses on a characteristic scale called the skin depth, which is much smaller than the wavelength of the microwaves.

For mobile phone signals even a single sheet of aluminium foil is sufficient to block a signal.